# C# Task Scheduler Access Denied Issue

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I am creating a task scheduler from c# code using         ***Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler*** library.

Following is my code:

```
TaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask();

Principal.UserId = "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM";
Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;

RegistrationInfo.Description = erpTaskSchedulerModel.SchedulerName;

taskDefinition.Triggers.Add(SetTrigger(erpTaskSchedulerModel));

taskDefinition.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

taskDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(erpTaskSchedulerModel.ExePath, erpTaskSchedulerModel.ExeParameters, null));

taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(erpTaskSchedulerModel.SchedulerName, taskDefinition);
```

I am getting following error from the last line of code.:

**Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

Because of this my task is not getting scheduled.  This issue occurs in IIS hosted site.  How can I remove this issue?

Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: the code is probablly running as a restricted user.  You need admin rights to add scheduled tasks as a specifc user

Comment: You haven't ensured that you have the correct privileges to create the task. Given your statement that this occurs on an _"IIS hosted site"_, the marked duplicate seems most applicable, though there is no shortage of answers to questions involving `E_ACCESSDENIED`.

Comment: I have gone through the question asked by Jay S. It is stated in the answer provided by Jay S: able to solve the problem though not completely.  @Peter Duniho is that only proper way to achieve it?

Comment: You have to do _something_ to gain the necessary privileges. In the other answer, I believe the "not completely" refers to the fact that they wanted to be able to use the "Backup Operators" group, but that group did not have sufficient privileges when trying to elevate to the "LOCAL SYSTEM" account, but that wouldn't necessarily apply in your case. You just need to elevate to/impersonate an admin account.